# collation conflict sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i issue a SQL query, sometimes I get the following error message:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I often solve this problem just make both table collation same. so i need to know is there any quick way to fix this issue.

I'd like to put *something special* in my SQL query as a result if collation is not same for both table in sql query then also query will work perfectly without any error. is there any solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can force which collation by using the [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) clause.

i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Server2.dbo.Table2 T2
ON T1.Name = T2.Name COLLATE database_default
```

Collation conflicts are common when joining tables between two databases or servers, especially if the version of the DB is different.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a collation in a query using the [collate clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx):

```
where  col1 = col2 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a possibility that both the servers use different Collations. If yes then you would get an error similar to then one I mentioned at the top of this topic. What you should do in this case?

1. You can alter the default Collation of either of the table columns/fields, but this could have a ripple effect for other tables currently in use with the altered table.
2. Use COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT keyword while matching the columns/fields

like:

```
SELECT T1.EmployeeName, T2.DeptName
FROM ServerA.dbo.EmpTab T1
JOIN ServerB.dbo.DeptTab T2
ON T1.DeptCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
= T2.DeptCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```