# SQL Collation conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having collation issues when doing an sql query that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO (table1) (...)
SELECT (...)
FROM (table 2)
WHERE X NOT IN (SELECT Y from (table1)
```

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Chinese_PRC_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

I see a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534123/collation-conflict-sql-server) but when I try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO (table1) (...)
    SELECT (...)
    FROM (table 2)
    WHERE X NOT IN (SELECT Y from (table1) COLLATE database_default
```

I get a syntax error:

```
 "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLLATE'."
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `COLLATE`:

```
INSERT INTO (table1) (...)
SELECT (...)
FROM (table 2)
WHERE X NOT IN (SELECT Y COLLATE database_default from table1);
```

Please note that `NOT IN` could be tricky if column `Y` is nullable. It is good practice to secure code by adding:

```
WHERE X NOT IN(SELECT Y COLLATE database_default from table1 WHERE Y IS NOT NULL);
```